# SAPUI5: How can I redirect to a NotFound page after change the id in the url?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, binding, sapui5

I have two XML views and I can navigate between them using routing. In the first view I have a list with weekdays, in the second view I have a list with meals related to a weekday. The thing I want to do: if I change the weekday ID in the URL to 8 for example I want to show the Not found page. This is my controller, I don't know if I can use the _onBindingChange function:

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/demo/nav/controller/BaseController"], function(BaseController) {
"use strict";
return BaseController.extend("sap.ui.demo.nav.controller.DETAIL", {
    onInit: function() {
        var oRouter = this.getRouter();
        oRouter.getRoute("meal").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);

    },
    _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {

        var oArgs, oView;
        oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");

        oView = this.getView();

        var oTable = oView.byId("mealListID");

        var listbinding = oTable.getBinding("items");

        var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("dayId", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oArgs.dayId);


        listbinding.filter([oFilter]);


    },
    _onBindingChange: function(oEvent) {
        // No data for the binding
        if (!this.getView().getBindingContext()) {

            this.getRouter().getTargets().display("notFound");

        }
    }

});});
```

Comment: You should post code here in the question, not just point to your entire codebase somewhere else. Links to other sites stop working over time, and this question will stop making any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reroute in the **_onRouteMatched** method.

```
_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
//window.location.hash will give the hash value, so look for your id and re-route to other page

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `_onBindingChange`. See [this documentation](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/89de2f43b91d470daa8121a0b4ba35cc.html) and the code [around here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-masterdetail-app/blob/master/webapp/controller/Detail.controller.js#L123) in the Master-Detail demo app for a best-practice example, which does pretty much the same you are proposing above.